# AJAX request to PHP file, security and accessibility for the PHP file

Tags: php, ajax, security, post

I have a small AJAX script which passes GET variables to a receiving PHP file, let's call it `AJAX_RECEIVER.php`.

This file does a Database query and based on the GET `key-value` pairs, returns a responseText, which is then fed into an HTML element.

I have some questions

1) how to prevent someone from randomly accessing this AJAX_RECEIVER.php file by typing it in the URL of the browser?

2) How do I ensure that only a "valid" logged in user is able to get a meaningful response from the `AJAX_RECEIVER.php`?
file

3) How do I pass key-value pairs to this AJAX_RECEIVER.php using POST?

4) I guess I could set the values of a Session Variable to something that signifies that a valid user is logged in, and pass it to the AJAX_RECEIVER.php using POST, which does a check and returns something legit only if it's a valid user, I'm just a bit unsure if this is the best way to do this... or is there any other way?

Sorry if my question sounds a bit repetitive or may have been answered elsewhere, any help would be greatly appreciated.
P.S. I don't want to use JQUERY (quite happy with Javascript and I don't want to spend another few days learning another thing if I can do the same thing with simple Javascript)

Comment: Simply add the session check in `AJAX_RECEIVER.php` file. Your all problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, but i guess this means I have to pass the key-vaues to the AJAX_RECEIVER.php via post.. how do I do that?

Comment: You don’t have to pass any parameter in post for authenticating. Your get request will work fine. Simple add the session check in top of the file. You will need to pass the post parameter for authentication if you are not using session

Comment: Look for the javascript that is doing the ajax call and you can change the type from get to post there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to prevent someone from randomly accessing this AJAX_RECEIVER.php file by typing it in the URL of the browser?

You can't.

> How do I ensure that only a "valid" logged in user is able to get a meaningful response from the AJAX_RECEIVER.php?

The same way that you ensure that only a valid, logged-in user is able to get a meaningful response from any of your other PHP programs. (Presumably, you are using some kind of session-based authentication, use that).

> How do I pass key-value pairs to this AJAX_RECEIVER.php using POST?

There are lots of ways. Passing a `FormData` object to `fetch` is probably the simplest.

```
var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));
fetch('/AJAX_RECEIVER.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
});
```

> I guess I could set the values of a Session Variable to something that
>   signifies that a valid user is logged in,

That is how most login systems work

> and pass it to the AJAX_RECEIVER.php using POST

Just continue to use the same session cookie to pass *that* data. Don't copy it to the body of the post request. That would make it easy to forge logged in status.

Comment: Thanks Quentin, So I did something like this instead of using Form Data, is it 'safe' you think?
var AJ = new XMLHttpRequest();
AJ.onreadystatechange = function() {
if((AJ.readyState == 4) && (AJ.status == 200))
{ var elem = document.getElementById("EL_ID");
 elem.innerHTML = AJ.responseText;
}}
var PARAM = "NAME1=" + VALUE1 + "&NAME2=" + VALUE2;
AJ.open("POST", "AJAX_RECEIVER.php" + PARAM , true);
AJ.send(PARAM);
It is working fine; sending and getting desired results, wondering if this is 'good practice' or some holes are open; great if you could advise, thanks mate!